# How to get image coordinate and corresponding location coordinate of a geo-referenced image in andriod

Tags: java, android

In my android app, I have a geo-referenced image which I am going to use as map. So I need to divide it into tiles. For that I want its top left and bottom right image coordinate(x,y) with location coordinate of corresponding image coordinates using java code which is supported in android. Can anyone help me with the solution.